# Configure pkexec to only prompt for password once

Tags: sudo, password, policykit, pkexec

When using `sudo` there is a timeout where you don't have to type the password again for x minutes when you run `sudo` again. Is it possible to get the same thing for graphical applications which use `pkexec`? I've looked everywhere and all I can find is guides to disable the password completely and/or do it for a single application. How can I configure `pkexec` to only prompt for a password once in x minutes system-wide?

Comment: take a look here please. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409636/pkexec-how-do-i-set-a-custom-timeout-for-auth-admin-keep-when-writting-a-pkexe

Comment: @nobody I think that answer is for application developers? It doesn't seem to be referring to setting a system-wide policy. It also mentions a hard-coded five minute timeout, which has not been my experience. I get a zero minute timeout.